# Product topology and relativization

Tags: general-topology, product-space

$(X_1,\tau_1)$ and $(X_2.\tau_2)$ are topological spaces with $Y_1\subset X_1; Y_2\subset X_2$. Let $X_1\times X_2=X; Y_1\times Y_2=Y $. Prove that the product topology on $Y$ obtained from topologies $\tau_i|Y_i$ is the same as the relativization to $Y$, the product topology on $X$.

In the above question what do we mean by relativization and what to show, I am not getting the meaning of the question. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Although the wording is strange, I believe they are trying to say that the restriction of the product topology of $X_1\times X_2$ to $Y_1\times Y_2$ is the same topology as the subspace topology.

Comment: Relativization (aka restriction) is the process of putting the subspace topology on a subspace. In other words, if we use $\tau\!\mid_Y=\{S\cap Y\mid S\in\tau\}$ to denote restriction and $\tau_1\times\tau_2$ to denote the product topology (abuse of notation), you are asked to show $\tau_1\!\mid_{Y_1}\!\times\,\tau_2\!\mid_{Y_2}\,=(\tau_1\times\tau_2)\mid_{Y_1\times Y_2}$.

Comment: Given a topological space $X$ and a subset $Y \subset X$, the *relative topology on $Y$* and the *subspace topology on $Y$* are exactly the same. This applies to $Y_1 \subset X_1$, and to $Y_2 \subset X_2$, and to $Y_1 \times Y_2 \subset X_1 \times X_2$ (where, in the case of $X_1 \times X_2$, the relevant topology is the product topology).

Answer (score 1):

The set $Y$ is a subset of $X$. Therefore, if you consider to product topology on $X$, a natural topology to consider on $Y$ is the relative topology: if $A\subset Y$, then $A$ is open if $A=Y\cap A^\star$, for some open subset $A^\star$ of $X$.

On the other hand, since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are subsets of $X_1$ and $X_2$ then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ get the relativa topology from $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively. And then you have the product topology on $Y_1\times Y_1$.

The problem is to prove that these two topologies on $Y_1\times Y_2$ are equal.